# java.util.Map and google cache implementation(com.google.common.cache.Cache) difference

Tags: java, collections, guava

I am planning to use Google's cache implementation (`com.google.common.cache.Cache`) along with `java.util.set`. Below is a code block showing the results of using `Set.contains()` to check if an element exists in a set.

When the element type of the `Set` is `java.util.Map`, it is actually checking if the `key` and `Value` of the map passed are similar to any of the elements found in the `Set`. So my understanding is that the Key and Value objects `equals()` methods are called to check if any of the elements have the same values.

On the other hand Google's implementation seems to be using `obj1==obj2` type comparison.

```
    final Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(1,1);
    final Map<Integer, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2.put(1,1);

    Set<Map<Integer, Integer>> s2 = new HashSet<>();
    s2.add(map);
    System.out.println("Set.contains() check with a different instance of java.util.Map but same (key,value)=>(1,1): "+s2.contains(map2));


    final Cache<Integer, Integer> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().expireAfterWrite(10L, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();
    cache.put(1,1);
    final Cache<Integer, Integer> cache2 = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().expireAfterWrite(10L, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();
    cache2.put(1,1);

    Set<Cache<Integer,Integer>> s = new HashSet<>();
    s.add(cache);
    System.out.println("Set.contains() check with a different instance of com.google.common.cache.Cache but same (key,value)=>(1,1): "+s.contains(cache2));
```

Here is the output from the above code.

```
Set.contains() check with a different instance of java.util.Map but same (key,value)=>(1,1): true
Set.contains() check with a different instance of com.google.common.cache.Cache but same (key,value)=>(1,1): false
```

My questions are:

Is this expected behavior or a bug?

Or did I miss anything with the test I performed?

I would also appreciate if anyone with better understanding of Google's Cache implementation give me some idea if this was a known issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Note that, in any case, putting a *mutable* object (like a map) into a `HashSet` is very dangerous. Even **IF** your example worked: When you modify the `map` object after it was put into the set `s2`, then the set `s2` would become inconsistent. (That means that even if you did the same modification afterwards to `map2`, the lookup would most likely not work any more, and the first output would also print `false`!)

Comment: I agree that could cause issues but in this specific case I am only checking if there is an element in the set before adding it and not modifying the elements.

Comment: "Known issue" makes it sound like this isn't the intended behavior.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Not saying it is an issue(known or unknown :) ) Just asking if there was a reason why the deep equal was not implemented or the Guava team just left it as it is now. Or if I misunderstood how it should work. Or if the Cache is expected to behave in the same way as that of the Map when it comes to comparing objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is because `HashMap` 's [`equal()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractMap.java#AbstractMap.equals%28java.lang.Object%29) implementation provides deep equal checking while guava [`Cache`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.guava/guava/16.0.1/com/google/common/cache/LocalCache.java#LocalCache.LocalManualCache) doesn't provide this equal method it uses it from Object

Answer (score 2):

Caches deliberately use reference equality, because equality of different caches doesn't mean much: if one millisecond later, one of the entries expires, then the caches are no longer equal.

If you want content equality, then there's an easy workaround: `cache1.asMap().equals(cache2.asMap())`.